# Old programmer needs STL secrets

Tags: c++, vector, stl

When I learned C++ they warned me not to use the STL.  It was new, buggy, and inefficient.  Recently I found myself creating a container for a new project, and realized it was probably a case of [NIH](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Not_invented_here) and I should try the STL <vector>.

Unfortunately it does not work.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#include <vector>

class test {
    public:
    int x;
};

int main(int argc,char *argv[]) {
    std::vector<test> obj;
    test *tmp=new test();
    tmp->x=42;
    obj.push_back(tmp);
    }
```

g++ warns me that there is no matching function for push_back, and that push_back takes const value_type& as a parameter.  I have tried many casts to force this, but it refuses to budge.

I have now wasted more time trying to do it the "right" way than it would have taken to write yet-another container and debug it.

If this sounds like rage and frustration, you are perceptive.  I have already found several questions like mine, but the answers prove extraordinarily difficult to follow.  If this were a site where flames would fly, I would expect to get toasted for this.  I have lurked around stackoverflow for a couple years, and I bet there is someone that could "explain it like I am five."

Is there a one-liner incantation to force the cast to work?  If not, how are these vectors supposed to be used?

Comment: Why are you allocating tmp on the heap? also: `obj.push_back(*tmp);`

Comment: @Borgleader are you telling him to leak the object?

Comment: [`push_back` doesn't take a pointer argument](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/push_back).

Comment: @sehe No, I should probably have mentioned that push_back will copy it's argument, and therefore tmp should be deleted right after the call to push_back.

Comment: @Borgleader Better yet, in first place, it shouldn't even have been created at all.

Comment: @H2CO3 that's why I started with "Why are you allocating on the heap".

Comment: Also, "don't use the STL" is still a valid piece of advice. Don't use the STL because it's non-standard. Use the C++ Standard Library instead.

Comment: When did you learn C++?

Comment: @Borgleader (yup, seen it :)

Comment: Also, if you need "STL secrets" might I suggest [Effective STL](http://www.amazon.com/Effective-STL-Specific-Standard-Template/dp/0201749629/)

Comment: There are reasons to create an object on the heap and not want to copy it.  However, those reasons can usually be eliminated through a little extra effort.  Moving from non-STL to STL, and from pointers to references, takes a good amount of rethinking and practice.

Comment: @H2CO3 I guess the OP meant "C++ standard library", but used an obsolete terminology. I often find people using the acronym STL to refer to the various collections in the standard library. I just reached for my old copy of *The C++ programming language* (2nd ed.) and even Stroustrup says (section 16.2.3 - STL containers, p.441): **"The standard library and containers and iterators (often called STL framework[...]"**.

Comment: @Lorenzo Sounds reasonable. Even "Effective C++" confuses the STL and the stdlib.

Answer (score 11):

Lose the pointer

```
std::vector<test> obj;
test tmp;
tmp.x=42;
obj.push_back(tmp);
```

You have a vector of `test` not `test*` so I'm not sure why you tried to involve pointers. One of the **massive** advantages of the STL is that it allows you to avoid pointers, which as an experienced C++er, I'm sure you know are a major cause of bugs.

Comment: Wow! It was that easy?  I knew I should not be implementing this again with pages of pointer manipulation. I will try to stop thinking with pointers.

Comment: If you are concerned about performance, don't ever do such a thing as stopping to think with pointers: One of the most frequent performance bugs with people using standard containers excessively is the tendency to needlessly copy stuff around. I've seen people making vectors of vectors of strings, and then wondering why assigning the whole thing is so slow... So, I advocate to also think about using `vector<test*>`. Both `vector<test>` and `vector<test*>` have their legitimate uses, never needlessly ignore either one. Also, be aware that passing an object to `push_back()` copies it.

Answer (score 3):

Do one of these 2 things

```
std::vector<test*> obj;
test *tmp=new test;
tmp->x=42;
obj.push_back(tmp);
```

Or

```
std::vector<test> obj;
test tmp;
tmp.x=42;
obj.push_back(tmp);
```

If you declare a `vector` of `test` objects, then push_back a `test` object.
If you declare a `vector` of `test` pointers, then push_back a `test *`.

Comment: It's worth noting that in the first case the destructors for the test objects won't be called as the vector is holding pointers. So the 2nd version is preferred.

Comment: It gets confusing learning to move away from pointers and heap allocation, but it's worth looking at.  The consideration of the difference between the two solutions above is whether a copy of `test tmp` is safe/expensive to make.  The first block does not copy the created object, while the second creates a temporary copy on the stack and pushes a copy into the vector.  Note that the upside of the copy method is the lack of need to free those pointers.

Comment: @ash Move if you don't want to copy. Don't do the first thing.

Comment: @Cat Plus Plus - I'm trying to help the Op.  Without knowing all of the factors behind the decisions going into his code, the first can be the right solution for his situation.

Comment: @ash: No. No owning raw pointers. `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<T>>` maybe, but completely unnecessary. The copy in `push_back` is trivially avoidable by using `emplace_back` or `push_back(std::move(tmp))`. Don't do the first thing.

Answer (score 1):

Along with losing the pointer as @John (quite rightly, in my opinion) suggested, I'd *add* a ctor to your `test` class:

```
class test { 
    int x;
public:
    test(int x) : x(x) {}
};
```

This can be used for an implicit conversion, so you can also skip the `tmp` variable, leaving something like:

```
std::vector<test> t;

t.push_back(42);
```

...and the compiler will use the ctor to automatically convert the `42` to a `test` object with its `x` value set to `42`.

If you want to protect against accidentally converting a random `int` to a `test`, you can go for a halfway point. Make the ctor `explicit`, and explicitly convert in the call to `push_back`:

```
class test { 
    int x;
public:
    explicit test(int x) : x(x) {}
};

// ...

std::vector<test> t;

t.push_back(test(42));
```

Oh, I should probably mention one other detail: assuming you're using a (fairly) new compiler, you might want to use `emplace_back` instead of `push_back`. Given a chance, it'll create the new object in place instead of copying it into the vector. It won't make any real difference for a tiny class like your `test` (only containing a single `int`), but for something large that's expensive to copy, the difference can be significant.

Answer (score 1):

You should not store C++ pointers in std collections.  You store the objects themselves as John suggests.  A host of very tricky memory bugs results from using raw pointers.
Perhaps your teacher had done this if he believed the STL was buggy. It is really robust.  The STL can seem inefficient if you store big objects in collections as these will be copied, which is expensive in time and memory. Hence the belief about inefficiency which is also wrong.
The trick is to use [smart pointers](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/libs/smart_ptr/smart_ptr.htm).  These make heap allocation much easier and work brilliantly with the STL. It is then efficient and not at all buggy.  It is much better than is ever reasonable to write oneself.

Comment: Vector elements will be moved, not copied, wherever possible. Otherwise correct and very sound advice. +1 *thumbs up*

Comment: lol - tricky bugs and pointers.  Sounds familiar.  They created an entire progamming language, and Operating systems, based on that.

Comment: Even with copy-only items, concern for copying speed is *usually* misplaced. Assuming items are being copied, they still aren't copied terribly often -- the number of times tends to a constant, typically around 3.